# Password Strength: Compound Words

Tags: passwords, brute-force, dictionary

I’m familiar with [XKCD’s Correct Horse Battery Stable example](https://www.xkcd.com/936/) but I am wondering about one aspect of password strength.

Dictionary words are an easy target for password crackers. If you compound a word, such as `batteryhorse` which clearly is not in the dictionary, do password crackers have an easier time of it than just by brute-forcing a 12-letter combination? In other words is it more or less crackable than, say, `abcdefgjihk` or `qpwosugnelso`?

For this question, I am leaving out other characters or longer passwords. I am just asking whether some cracking algorithms handle compound words better than brute force.

Comment: This is a question if an attacker is an irrational moron or a calculating sharpie.

Comment: @techraf The attacker is a piece of software. That makes it a calculating moron, I suppose.

Comment: A piece of software does not pay the electricity bill to run itself.